# How can i speed up the request in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a table -

```
create table LiveMovie
(
    id           int auto_increment
        primary key,
    pitchID          int                                  not null,
    UID              char(20)                             null,
    roomID           int                                  not null,
    imgID            int                                  not null,
    start_time       datetime                             not null,
    request_index      int                                not null,
    constraint live__uid
        unique (UID)
)

create index live_pitchID_roomID
    on LiveMovie (pitchID, roomID);

create index live_roomID_time
    on LiveMovie (roomID, start_time);
```

In which there are about 5 million records.
And upon request - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT pitchID FROM LiveMovie WHERE roomID=? GROUP BY pitchID) AS counter;`the request takes about 15 seconds
Can I somehow speed up the request?
Execution plan -

```
ID   select_type  table         type   possible_key            key      key_len     ref    rows      Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY',  '<derived2>',  'ALL',    NULL,                NULL,    NULL,      NULL,   '19',     NULL
'2', 'DERIVED', 'LiveMovie',    'ref', 'live_roomID_time', 'live_roomID_time', '4', 'const', '19', 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Why not add an index to the fields that you filter for?

Comment: Why don't you do the count directly on the table?

Comment: Also, can you share the execution plan for the given query?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, I wrote the wrong index here

Answer (score 1):

I would have an index based on your WHERE condition first in the index, THEN the group by such as

```
index on (roomId, pitchID)
```

Then, since all you care about is how many, I would do

```
select count( distinct pitchID )
   FROM LiveMovie 
   WHERE roomID = ?
```

By having the index by room, you are getting just those records first and done.  By having the pitchid in the second position, that will optimize the distinct count result.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you select twice?
Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(pitchID) as counter FROM LiveMovie WHERE roomId=? GROUP BY pitchID;
```

Comment: Not quite right as I need to find the count of these fields found